# Node.js Proxy with custom Http(s) Agent and Connect.js Middleware

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, node.js-connect, har

I've put together a proxy server in Node that needs the ability to tunnel https requests over tls and that all works. Using the the following two packages this was extremely easy to setup: [proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy), [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent). My issue is that I'm trying to capture HAR files using [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) as a middleware layer and I'm getting the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:357
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:180:21)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/proxy/proxy.js:233:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:473:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

The is as simple as the following and it only seems to happen when I'm using [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and proxying through my local browser(this proxy is actually being used with [BrowserStackLocal](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing)). When I pass through the proxy from anything other than my local machines browser, it's like it doesn't even know the middleware exists.

So basically, I just need to get connect working in this scenario and I'm not sure if I need to pause something and resume, or what... any ideas would be greatly appreciated. The base code is below:

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const proxy = require('proxy');
const Agent = require('https-proxy-agent');
const connect = require('connect');
const har = require('./har');

const middleware = connect();

middleware.use(har({
  harOutputDir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'har/')
}));

const server = proxy(http.createServer(middleware));
server.agent = new Agent('http://localhost:8081');

server.listen(8081)
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Just a note: the har middleware is not modifying headers at all.

Comment: is the ./har middleware sending data on the response object? If so, a header will be set and the error occurs for the second setHeader

Comment: @Myonara no- all it does is read data from the response and "next()" the issue is present even without the "./har" middleware in place.

Comment: On the client side can you identify, what was sended instead of the second header answer?

Comment: @Myonara I'm not sure what you mean... it appears as if connect or the proxy server are sending headers before the other gets a chance to do anything. If I had to guess I would say the proxy is sending it's headers first being that it fails with connect in place. I'm wondering if i can pause the response and have it wait for connect to it's thing. I'm trying to do this without having to modify the proxy and submit a PR. Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proxy` hasn't been maintained in a while. Builds are not passing, last commit don't pass tests. The source of the stack trace you've put up is coming from [here in Line 233](https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy/blob/master/proxy.js#L233) - buggy library code.

Writing a similar proxy is trivial. Following code illustrates how to create one.

```
const http = require('http');
const urlP = require('url');

const proxiedServer = 'http://localhost:8888';

// Proxy server
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(`Proxy: Got ${req.url}`);

  const _r = http.request(
    Object.assign(
      {},
      urlP.parse(proxiedServer),
      {
        method: req.method,
        path: req.url
      }
    ),
    _res => {
      res.writeHead(_res.statusCode, _res.headers);
      _res.pipe(res);
    }
  );

  req.pipe(_r);

}).listen(3124, () => {
  console.log("Listening on 3124");
});


// Regular server. Could be Express
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('Proxied server: ', req.url);
  let b = '';
  req.on('data', c => {
    b += c;
  });
  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Proxied server: ', b);
  });
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('ok');
}).listen(8888, () => {
  console.log('proxied server listening on 8888');
});
```

Your code using your own custom proxy would look like the following:

```
const urlP = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const connect = require('connect');
const har = require('./har');

const proxiedServer = 'http://localhost:8888';

// Proxy server
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(`Proxy: Got ${req.url}`);

  const _r = http.request(
    Object.assign(
      {},
      urlP.parse(proxiedServer),
      {
        method: req.method,
        path: req.url
      }
    ),
    _res => {
      res.writeHead(_res.statusCode, _res.headers);
      _res.pipe(res);
    }
  );

  req.pipe(_r);

}).listen(3124, () => {
  console.log("Listening on 3124");
});

const middleware = connect();
middleware.use(har({
  harOutputDir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'har/')
}));

middleware.use((req, res) => {
  console.log('Proxied server: ', req.url);
  let b = '';
  req.on('data', c => {
    b += c;
  });
  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Proxied server: ', b);
  });
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('ok');
});


http.createServer(middleware).listen(8888, () => {
  console.log('proxied server listening on 8888');
});
```

Comment: Ok- thanks for the help... I actually started writing my own but ran into one too many issues tunneling https over http. I figured out that I the agent was the solution to that vs trying to create certs for anything passing through the proxy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did the snippet in the answer help?

Comment: Yes, I had actually looked into it and was planning to clean it up a little and submit a PR but ended up just started writing my own as you suggested ... it's a bit more involved because of the need I have for agents and swapping to TLS when necessary but hopefully it helps someone. I'm essentially writing a JavaScript solution to replace. BrowserMobb Procy. Thanks for the help!